# How to open root directory on second HDD?

Tags: centos, hard-disk, root

My situation is very specific. I've applied chmod -R 777 / on my CentOS 7 server, so my system screwed up on next reboot. I took server HDD home and connected it via SATA cable to my home PC.
Now I've got other install (which is OK on 8gb VM drive) of CentOS 7 running on my Virtual Machine and server HDD connected to that VM. I can only access /home directory on server HDD, but my backups are in another directory so I need a nice way to access root directory on my server HDD.

Any suggestions?

[image]

UPD: output of "mount"

```
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,seclabel,size=1932840k,nr_inodes=483210,mode=755)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,seclabel,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,mode=755)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,seclabel,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuacct,cpu)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/mapper/centos-root on / type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux type selinuxfs (rw,relatime)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=32,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime,seclabel)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,seclabel)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
sunrpc on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/0/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdb1 on /run/media/root/56ffd140-13f1-47d9-b818-c49c841aed84 type xfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/mapper/centos-home on /run/media/root/ea53d717-9ab0-4c70-ab8a-b0e2936c8ff8 type xfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Comment: What's the error message you see?

Comment: There is no error. When I open my server HDD on GUI it just shows me server's home directory. I need the root one.

Comment: please post the output of `mount` in your question

Comment: There is another 'ejectable' drive in there (the 524Mb Volume in the picture) isn't that the partition containing root? If that is not it try to navigate to `/run/media/root/56ffd140-13f1-47d9-b818-c49c841aed84`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have mounted the wrong partition of the server drive. Unmount it manually (`umount /run/media/root/ea53d717-....`) and then check how the server drive is partitioned (`fdisk`,`sfdisk`, `cfdisk`, whatever). Then remount the correct partition you just found using `mount /drive/partition /media/mountpoint`.

Comment: A little bit disappointed how to do it. Could you please explain? BTW CentOS mounted HDD itself on startup.

Comment: Ok, now it says unknown filesystem LVM2_member.